# Determine where $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ is increasing and decreasing and find absolute extrema on $(0,2\pi)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So this is the problem: determine where $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ is increasing and decreasing and find absolute extrema on $(0,2\pi)$.

I took the derivative and found it to be $f'(x)=2\cos(2x)$.
When setting the derivative equal to $0$ I get $x=45*(2*n8-1)$. Now by seeing this I know that it shouldn't equal $0$, right?

Comment: $x=45*(2*n8-1)$ - What is this??

Answer (score 1):

Derivative is zero at 45*(2*n-1) degrees, for n=1 to n=4, as you said. So at 45, 135, 225, and 315 degrees, the original function is at relative minimums and maximums, since the derivative is zero and the slope is changing sign. As was asked, it is increasing or decreasing between these points, and the extrema will be found at these points.  (Extrema for a sin function will be 1, -1 so that is done.)
Maximum will be at 45 and 225 degrees, so the intervals for increasing will be 0-45, 135-225, and 315-360 degrees.  Other intervals are decreasing. 
(BTW, you switched from radians to degrees, which can be very confusing. Stick with radians, then convert after you have the answer, if you need to.)